# Eliminar cualquier texto y espacio después de un segundo espacio en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql

Estimadxs, saludos, tengo una duda sobre como obtener solo las dos primeras palabras de un texto en `MSSQL`, por ejemplo si el texto fuera:

```
'Hola Pedro mi nombre es Raúl' 
'Este adiós solo es temporal'
'Nada quedará después de la caída del meteorito'
```

Quisiera que solo me mostrara las dos primeras palabras:

```
'Hola Pedro'
'Este adiós'
'Nada quedará'
```

Entiendo que para esto debo usar las instrucciones `LEFT` y `CHARINDEX`, de esta forma hice lo siguiente:

```
SELECT Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle.CLI_apenom 'Nombre Completo', 
        LEFT(Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle.CLI_apenom, 
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle.CLI_apenom) > 0
                THEN CHARINDEX(' ', Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle.CLI_apenom) - 1
            ELSE 0
        END) AS Recorte
FROM Mensaje_Electronico_Encabezado 
    INNER JOIN Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle 
        ON Mensaje_Electronico_Encabezado.MEE_Id = Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle.MEE_id
```

Pero, esto solo me devuelve la primer palabra, ¿Cómo lo corrijo para obtener la segunda palabra y que quede como ya mencioné?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque en teoría, el `LEFT` es lo que debes de usar, para longitudes variables sugiero usar substring puesto que previene errores si tienes que restar algo a la longitud calculada (por ejemplo que en vez de espacio fueran comas y no quieres que se muestren las comas).

La explicación básica ya la dieron.

- La posición del segundo espacio se realiza anidando la función `CHARINDEX` usando una para obtener el primer espacio y eso usarlo como tercer argumento de la otra función y poder obtener el segundo espacio.
- Después usamos `SUBSTRING` con base cero para que tome un caracter menos que la longitud que enviamos (así no incluimos el espacio).
- Por último, como medida de seguridad, usamos una combinación de `ISNULL( NULLIF())` para regresar la cadena original en caso de que tenga menos de 2 espacios.

Dejo el código de ejemplo con varios casos de prueba

```
WITH Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle  AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('Hola Pedro mi nombre es Raúl' ),
                ('Este adiós solo es temporal'),
                ('Nada quedará después de la caída del meteorito'),
                ('Un Espacio'),
                ('SinEspacios'),
                (''),
                (NULL))x(CLI_apenom)
)
SELECT med.CLI_apenom,
    ISNULL( NULLIF( SUBSTRING( med.CLI_apenom, 0, CHARINDEX( ' ', med.CLI_apenom, CHARINDEX( ' ', med.CLI_apenom) + 1)), ''), med.CLI_apenom)
FROM Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle med;
```

**Edición:**

Dejo este código para que funcione con el segundo conjunto de espacios consecutivos, donde los conjuntos de espacios pueden ser un solo espacio. Remplazo un `CHARINDEX` por la búsqueda de patrones `PATINDEX` para buscar el primer espacio que no está seguido de otro espacio. El resto de la fórmula se mantiene igual.

```
WITH Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle  AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('Hola Pedro mi nombre es Raúl' ),
                ('Hola                       Pedro mi nombre es Raúl' ),
                ('Este adiós solo es temporal'),
                ('Nada quedará después de la caída del meteorito'),
                ('Un Espacio'),
                ('SinEspacios'),
                (''),
                (NULL))x(CLI_apenom)
)
SELECT med.CLI_apenom,
    PATINDEX( '% [^ ]%', med.CLI_apenom),
    ISNULL( NULLIF( SUBSTRING( med.CLI_apenom, 0, CHARINDEX( ' ', med.CLI_apenom, PATINDEX( '% [^ ]%', med.CLI_apenom) + 1)), ''), med.CLI_apenom)
FROM Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle med;
```

Comment: ¿Y en caso de que existieran casos como el siguiente: 'Hola  Pedro mi nombre es Raúl' en donde 'Hola  ' tiene dos espacios en blanco como debería hacerlo? ¿Es correcto aplicar la función REPLACE(campo, '  ', ' ') dentro del segundo CHARINDEX quedando CHARINDEX(' ', REPLACE(campo, '  ', ' ')) + 1?

Comment: Es mucha casuística, porque tendrías que saber primero que el 'Hola' tendrá dos espacios, puede que tenga 1 o puede que tenga 3; tendrías que saber con antelación.

Comment: Para remplazar múltiples espacios con uno solo, es un proceso más complicado ¿Qué pasaría si no son 2 sino 3 o 4 espacios contiguos? También tendrías que considerar otros caracteres como tabulaciones o medios espacios que no coinciden con un espacio en blanco tradicional.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo revisa el código que agregué.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, muchas gracias por la explicación

Comment: Por cierto, de acuerdo al nombre de la columna tienes que considerar que no se debe de confiar sólamente en 2 palabras para identificar apellidos. Es común que haya apellidos de varias palabras (De La Rosa, Del Campo, etc) o que haya gente que solo utilice uno. Lo ideal es que puedan separar todo en distintas columnas desde el momento de ingresar los datos. Pero eso es ajeno al objetivo de esta pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

En efecto, tienes que usar `CHARINDEX` y `LEFT`. En tu caso la consulta quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```sql
SELECT LEFT(Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle.CLI_apenom, 
       CHARINDEX(' ', Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle.CLI_apenom, 
                 CHARINDEX(' ', Mensaje_Electronico_Detalle.CLI_apenom) +1)
```

El funcionamiento es el siguiente:

- El `LEFT` para obtener una cadena empezando desde la izquierda hasta una cantidad X de caracteres que colocamos, el `CHARINDEX` hace referencia a ese número de caracteres.
- El `CHARINDEX` principal (el que engloba al segundo `CHARINDEX`) lo que hace es obtener el segundo espacio de la columna colocada.
- El segundo `CHARINDEX` obtiene el primer espacio de la cadena y su posición aumentada en 1 servirá al primer `CHARINDEX` como referencia para el inicio de la búsqueda del segundo espacio.